# loading sequence from except

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two tables.

```
var cardtagtable = (from u in db.CardTagTables
                    where u.FKCardTagID == cardtable.cardID
                    select u.CardTagName).ToList();

var tagtable = (from u in db.TagTables
                select u.TagName).ToList();
```

Where in `cardtagtable` all names are selected to match with `tagtable`'s name.

**Condition-**

I want names from `tagtable` except names coming from `cardtagtable` list.

so I tried here-

```
 var list = tagtable.Except(cardtagtable);
```

This `list` is a sequence of all names except from `cardtagtable`.

Everything is all right till now.

Now I will use this `list` and pass it through the model.

```
var taglist = (from u in list
               select new TagModel {
                   tagId = u.TagID,
                   tagName = u.TagName,
                   tagCount = Convert.ToInt32(u.TagCount) == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(u.TagCount),
               }).ToList();
```

But this query says me no definition found for `Model` values from `u`.

How do I use this list here in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `u` is probably a `string` because your list is a `IEnumerable<string>`.The reason is that you are only selecting your `TagNames`, so your list contains only *tag names*, not your *TagTables*.Instead you need to select your  *elements* instead of just *tag names*:

```
var cardtagtable = (from u in db.CardTagTables
                    where u.FKCardTagID == cardtable.cardID
                    select u).ToList();

var tagtable = (from u in db.TagTables
                select u).ToList();
```

Then use `Where` and `Any` instead of `Except` like this:

```
var list = tagtable.Where(c => !cardtagtable
                             .Any(x => x.CardTagName == c.TagName));
```

Then your last query should work fine.

Update: Also there is a more elegant and optimized way to do that  (especially if this is `LINQ to SQL`).You can select only `CardtagNames` from `cardtagtable` and use `Contains` method:

```
var cardtagtable = (from u in db.CardTagTables
                    where u.FKCardTagID == cardtable.cardID
                    select u.CardTagName).ToList();

var tagtable = (from u in db.TagTables
                select u).ToList();

var list = tagtable.Where(c => !cardtagtable.Contains(c.TagName));
```

Comment: Though its defined by name `Any` but I have always been confused with it. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: `Any` returns a bool result and checks whether is there _any_ elements in the `cardtagtable` that mathches with the condition `(x.CardTagName == c.TagName)`, we want it to be **false** and use negation operator(!) to make it return `true` for `Where` when it's false.Actually this is the same as: `cardtagtable.All(x => x.CardTagName != c.TagName)` notice that I change `==` to `!=` and remove the negation operator.My explanation was horrible but if you see my update it's more elegant and less confusing :)